# Does the added spell damage from the Circle of Twilight Druid's Harvest Scythe get halved on a successful save?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, damage, unearthed-arcana

I'm playing a Circle of Twilight druid (a subclass from [Unearthed Arcana: Druid](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_Druid11272016_CAWS.pdf)) at level 5, and used the Harvest's Scythe ability for the first time with [*call lightning*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/call-lightning).

We had a situation where I hit three creatures with one bolt of lightning, where two of them failed the Dex saving throw and one succeeded. I rolled 5d10, and argued that the 3d10 lightning damage should be halved while the 2d10 added necrotic damage from Harvest's Scythe would count fully.

**Is this the correct way to do it, or should the necrotic damage have been halved as well?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## The necrotic damage gets halved

Your extra damage from Harvest Scythe is directly added to the spell's damage roll:

> When you roll damage for a spell, you can increase that damage by spending dice from the pool.

The result of the saving throw for *call lightning* is:

> A creature takes ... half as much damage on a successful one.

So the 3d10 lightning + Xd10 necrotic damage is halved in it's entirety due to the successful save.

### Disclaimer

Unearthed Arcana is playtest material and should be treated as such. If the Circle of Twilight were officially released it may be reworded to work as you interpreted or other changes could be made.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It makes sense how you and PJRZ put it. After all, the dex save signifies that the target avoids the brunt of the damage. The necrotic damage is 'channeled' through the spell, so I can accept that.

I am aware that it is playtest material, but I looked in the PHB and couldn't find an example of spells augmented in this way, so I wasn't sure on the intended mechanism.

Comment: @Shen consider looking at the damage option of the *bestow curse* spell for an equivalent effect.

Answer (score 10):

Unearthed arcana isn't quite official, but as it stands I think all the damage should be halved.

The Harvest's Scythe says

> When you roll damage for a spell, you can increase that damage...

And it states that this is added to the damage as necrotic.

So if a spell allows a creature to save for half-damage, there is no reason to believe this additional necrotic damage - even though it may be a different damage type - shouldn't be halved as well since its just adds to the total damage of the spell.